# how does this java recursion works in method with 2 arguments

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static int calcValue(int num1, int num2)
{
 if (num1 <= num2)
 return 0;
 else
 return calcValue(num1-1, num2) + 1;
}
```

`calcValue(5,1)` generates 4 as output

`calcValue(6,3)` generates 3 as output

I came across another recursion problem. I tried to run this also but not able to understand the code.

```
public static int guessProg( int num)
 {
 if (( num==0) || (num==1))
 return num;
 else
 return guessProg(num-1) + guessProg(num-2);
 }
```

`guessProg (3)` generates 2

`guessProg (12)` generates 144

**Can someone please help me understand the recursion call happening in the code above**

I have run the code. I need the explanation regarding how it generates the output I'm getting.

Comment: it counts how many times one can subtract 1 from num1 until it is equal to num2, basically doing difference between num1 and num2 as long as num1 is a bigger value then num2?

Comment: well, i'm having a hard time with recursion brother @maslan

Comment: so start with what I have written and then try to figure out how it works. It returns zero if both values are equal or num2 is greater then num1, otherwise it adds 1 to the result of the same function with num1-1. At some point num1 when being substracted 1 from it will be equal num2 and return 0

Comment: Take pen and paper and trace every step the method does. You'll understand better that way

Answer (score 4):

As you said, this method calculates the difference of the two input numbers, but it assumes the difference is positive (i.e. the first number is larger than or equal to the second number), since it cannot return a negative output.

If the method accepts two equal numbers, it returns 0 and the recursion ends.

Otherwise, it returns `calcValue(num1-1, num2) + 1`, which is equivalent to returning `num1-1 - num2 + 1`, which is equals to `num1 - num2`.

For example,

```
calcValue(5,2)
```

returns

```
calcValue(4,2) + 1
```

calcValue(4,2) returns

```
calcValue(3,2) + 1
```

calcValue(3,2) returns

```
calcValue(2,2) + 1
```

calcValue(2,2) returns

```
0
```

Now the result of each recursive call it returned to its caller, so

```
calcValue(2,2) + 1 becomes 0 + 1 == 1

calcValue(3,2) + 1 becomes 1 + 1 == 2

calcValue(4,2) + 1 becomes 2 + 1 == 3
```

which is the result of the original call to

```
calcValue(5,2)
```

Comment: hii can you tell me why (num1-1, num2) + 1 equivalent to returning num1-1 - num2 + 1 ??

Comment: @Kalariya_M Not `(num1-1, num2) + 1`. `(num1-1 - num2) + 1 == num1 - 1 - num2 + 1 == num1 -  num2 - 1 + 1 == num1 - num2`

Comment: but I think in the code it is like this (num1-1, num2) + 1 only.

Comment: @Kalariya_M Since `calcValue(x,y)` returns x-y, `calcValue(x-1,y)` returns x-1-y. Therefore `calcValue(x,y) == calcValue(x-1,y) + 1` (since `x-y == x-1-y+1`).